# My MVC project/ view/ controller not seeing my models in Umbraco app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm building an Umbraco 7.2.8 website

Under installation Models or Controllers folders didn't exist so I added them.

I added a model class to Models folder:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class QuoteRequest
    {
        public int People { get; set; }

        public int Days { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to use it in a view I get error `The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
@using MyNamespace.Models
```

My controller doesn't see it either. Why is that? What do I miss?

I tried to compile the project but with no effect. The project is compiling but no `MyNamespace.dll` is placed in bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you crate those folders in a separate project. If it's the case got to "Add references" and select your other project. 
If it's in the same project you need to use the same namespace as your project name/namespace. 
But I advise you to create a new project, it's a cleaner architecture.

You could also add your code into the App_code folder. The code will be available anywhere in your project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: All was in one project. I have recreated the installation first installing mvc application then installing umbraco into it. This worked